# $H_\kappa = \{A: |TC(A)|<\kappa \} = \{A: (\forall x \in TC(\{A\})) (|x|<\kappa)\}$ for singular cardinal $\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

$TC(A)$ is the transitive closure of $A$, $|x|$ is the cardinality of $x$, $\kappa$ is a cardinal number greater than $\aleph_0$ and $H_\kappa$ is the set of sets hereditarily of cardinality less than $\kappa$.

$\{A: |TC(A)|<\kappa \} \subseteq \{A: (\forall x \in TC(\{A\})) (|x|<\kappa)\}$ is obvious.

I could prove the other direction when $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal because for every $A \in \{A: (\forall x \in TC(\{A\})) (|x|<\kappa)\}$, the cardinality of each of $A, \bigcup A, \bigcup\bigcup A, ... $ is $< \kappa$ and the cardinality of their union, which is $TC(A)$, is $< \kappa$ as well.

I couldn't prove this part for singular cardinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good! Cause it's false when $\kappa$ is singular.

Let $A = \{\aleph_0,\aleph_1, \aleph_2, \dots\}$ (i.e. the set of all infinite cardinals $<\aleph_\omega$). Then $TC(\{A\}) = \{A\}\cup A\cup \aleph_\omega,$ so all $x\in TC(\{A\})$ have $|x|<\aleph_\omega.$ But $|TC(A)| = \aleph_\omega.$

Comment: Thanks. Looking back at it, the question does seem a bit silly or obvious. Should I delete it?

Comment: @HusseinAiman I don't think so... it's hardly the silliest or most obvious question on here (I've certainly asked sillier). If you really want to, and can't cause it's already answered, let me know and I can delete the answer.

Comment: there is no need to delete it